# How to find the line of PHP code which is using most CPU

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage

I am currently using EC2, and when testing (with locust.io) 100 concurrent users, I am achieving a RPS of 15. However, my CPU usage is nearly 100%.

Would anyone know how to track down the line/lines of PHP 7 code that are using most CPU, so I can optimize them?

Comment: Try deleting parts of code and calculate checking CPU usage. Maybe you have some loops that does too much useless work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest `xdebug` and `kcachegrind` to profile and analyse  the behaviour of your code.

Configure xdebug like this to enable profiling:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = xdebug.out.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

If you pass `XDEBUG_PROFILE` as POST or GET paramteter, xdebug will produce profiling data in the configured location.

Open these files with kcachegrind to drill into it.

Beware: Execution while profiling will take its time, and the files produced can get pretty big -- have an eye on diskusage.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few commercial products designed to explicitly solve these problems (often with decent free trials) in most languages and application types.

New Relic is really good at this for web software, being able to generate burn charts showing which methods are causing the most CPU cycles.  It also is able to specifically able to highlight bad queries, API calls and other external services.

It's my go to tool when trying to diagnose performance issues in PHP or Java web applications.

[image: New Relic Tracing]

AWS just launched 'X-Ray' which is billed to do a similar job, although I've not had a chance to try it.